# What URL for download OpenStreetMap tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, route-me

I download tiles from zoom level 11 - 16. 
But my map is small then other OSM map application.
....

I downloaded tiles from this URL: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4096/3659.png
It's work normally. but I noticed many tiles are different from http://www.openstreetmap.org

Thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine that there is any difference. http://www.openstreetmap.org uses the same source.

do you want to create an offline cache?

please respect the Tile-usage-policy: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy

Comment: I compare my map with iOS application name "OpenMaps". OpenMaps is big than my map in same zoom level !?

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, make sure you read and adhere to the tile usage policy. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy

Answer (score 7):

try using  downloadosmtiles.pl

very simple and will load what you need for example:
downloadosmtiles.pl --lat=49.5611:49.6282 --lon=10.951:11.0574 --zoom=13:14

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Geo-OSM-Tiles/downloadosmtiles.pl